# contact from 7 wordpress set value

Tags: wordpress

I am using contact form 7 plugin in wordpress .
I am trying to add a check box and when it is checked the value should be set to yes and no when not checked .
The yes and no fields should not be displayed on the front end .
Is there a way to do the above without using java script ,that is adding in the short codes provided by contact form 7 plugin

Comment: provide some code which what you have tried already

Answer (score 0):

```
[checkbox checkbox-378 label_first "red" "blue"]
```